# OpenMP program to demonstrate Linear Search using Section Clause

Tags: c, openmp

I used OpenMP to write a code to demonstrate a Linear Search using Section Clause. But my code shows number not found. Can please anyone help me to rectify the code please

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<omp.h>

void main(){

int find,found;
int *a;
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        a= (int[2]){1,5};
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        find = 1;
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        for (i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            if(a[i]==find){
                found=i;
            }
        }
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        if (found)
            printf("Number found at : %d\n",found);
        else
            printf("Number not found\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: In my guest, section are quite independent. Before entering section, some part of code should be initialized: `a` and `find` at least.
Then, you can have sections that will search in different part of `a`, for instance, first section search in even `a` indexes, second in odd...

Comment: Please explain your train of thought with this ... approach. The thing is, it doesn't work like this ... at all. Given how fundamentally wrong this code is, it is difficult to explain without understanding what you are *trying* to achieve.